# I cannot change the style of the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, texpad

maybe I am just a clod, but really I cannot make the bibliography to be in the author-year style with TextPad. It always deliver the same numeric style.
This is my code (sorry if there is alot stuf that does not matter, but I am not sure if there is some inconsistency with other portions of the code):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[5]{Dowe:1996}\\
\\
\cite{Dummett:2004}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And instead of an authoryear bibliography I get this:

[image]

What can I do in order to obtain something like "Dowe (1996)", without the square brackets and with the normal brackets? And what can I do in order to have a author-year bibliography instead that a numeric one?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Well, one has to patch the `author-year-comp` style. Could you post a full compilable code?

Comment: Did you run `latex` -> `biber` -> `latex`? Another thing, you are loading biblatex twice. Call it just once with all your options, like: `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}`. In general, it might help to take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/105447.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, you should not load biblatex twice, as you do. You should load it once, with all the options.

So, like:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
```

I can suppose that, as your code goes, biblatex is loaded in the first call with the default numeric style, and then the second call, when you try to set the style to `authoryear-comp`, is likely ignored (it does give you an "option clash for biblatex" error, though).
Anyway, current versions of biblatex have biber as default backend, you don't need to specify it, so you could simply use:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
```

Furthermore, to get citations in the format you mentioned, you should use `\textcite`.

Summing up:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{kastenholz}

\textcite{sarfraz}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which, once you run `(pdf)latex` -> `biber` -> `(pdf)latex`, will render:

[image]

Comment: yes now it works, also with simple \cite command :) thank you very much